# How to perform transient analysis LC series in Multisim

Tags: multisim, transient

I,m trying to perform transient analysis of next circuit:

[image: LC-series, transient analysis]

In t=0 switch is opened. Initial condition Vc=0, IL=4A.

But that doesn't work properly in Multisim (fig. above)

Voltage across Inductor does not match estimated value. Multisim show 120V in t=0, rather than 0V. How to fix it?

Link for Multisim Design (OneDrive): https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArJljGNjPhExtDGjTEqIZTgr4fCf

Comment: where is your switch?

Comment: Vladimir Cravero, thanks for reply. I,m not sure I need it.

Comment: Yes you need a switch.

Comment: Andy aka, thanks for reply. I add spst switch. How to use it in transient analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I measured voltage incorrectly. I assumed V(2) was Voltage across inductor, but it was voltage between left terminal of inductor and ground. Now I add new variable V(L1)-V(R1) and it fix everything. FYI: I did not need switch.